# Select child element based on parent's attribute value

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm looking for a css selector to select the inner div using the outerDivs class and data attribute. As I only want to be able to select the inner div if the data is set to true is this possible ?

```
<div class="outerDiv" data-Outer="true"> 
  <div class="inner"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You just deleted your newest question. There *is* actually a way, using pure CSS. If you undelete, or post a new question, I'll post the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39374918/3597276

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.outerDiv[data-Outer="true"] > .inner` should do the trick.