# On hover of child, change background color of parent container (CSS only)

Tags: html, css

This is a common question. It almost always gets immediately closed as a duplicate of this question: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/3597276)

The duplicate does a good job pointing out that parent elements cannot be targeted with CSS. But it provides little to no guidance for the original question, which may be caught in the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

In this particular case...

> How can the background color of the parent be changed when hovering the child?

...there is at least one CSS solution that may solve the problem.

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Using just `pointer-events` and `:hover`

**Compatibility of pointer-events:** [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events). Tested working on IE 11 and Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

- Set `pointer-events: none` on the div. The div will now ignore `:hover`.

  ```
  div {
      pointer-events: none;
  }
  ```
- Set the parent background to change on hover

  ```
  div:hover {
      background: #F00;
  }
  ```
- Set `pointer-events: auto` on the child so that the hover event is triggered only when the child is hovered

  ```
  div > a {
      pointer-events: auto;
  }
  ```

This works because the div is hovered when its child is hovered, and pointer events are activated with `auto` only on that child. Otherwise the parent ignores its hover pseudo-class.

#### Example

> **Note:** IE 11 and Edge require the child element to be `display: inline-block` or `display: block` for pointer events to work.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
div:hover {
  background: #F00;
}
div > a {
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <a href="#">Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Although you can't select parent elements with CSS, you may be able to accomplish the task with another method.

You want the background color of the parent to change when a child is hovered.

Consider using the `spread-radius` value of the [CSS `box-shadow` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

By creating a huge spread radius, you can change the color of the surrounding area (which is no different visually than the parent element).

```css
div {
    overflow: hidden;              /* 1 */
}

a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px red;  /* 2 */
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
div { 
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. `overflow: hidden` to limit child's box shadow
2. the `box-shadow` values are as follows:

`<box-shadow> : <offset-x> <offset-y> <blur-radius> <spread-radius> <color>`

- offset-x ~ horizontal distance from element
- offset-y ~ vertical distance from element
- `blur-radius` ~ makes the shadow increasingly bigger and transparent
- `spread-radius` ~ makes the shadow expand (without fading)

In this case, the first three values don't matter.

What you need is for the `spread-radius` to grow a lot, then have it clipped by the container with `overflow: hidden`.

---

***And what if there's another element in the container?***

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

```css
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px red;
}
div { 
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

You can apply a `z-index` to the sibling.

```
h2 { z-index: 1; }
```

And, because the elements happen to be in a flex container in this example, [they don't need to be positioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37310205/3597276) for `z-index` to work.

```css
h2 { z-index: 1; }

div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px red;
}
div { 
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach if you just want to change the background of the parent element is to fake it with a pseudo-element, consider this structure:

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  padding:2em;
  color:white;
}
a {
  color:white;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
a:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  z-index:-1;
  transition:background .5s linear;
}
a:hover:before {
  background:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div2">
  <h2>Here Some Title</h2>
  <a href="#">Hover Me</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This, of course, relies on the **a** not being positioned ... Good answer :-)

Comment: Yeah @vals in order to work this way you need that and other little things that cna't change, but allows to also use a bg image or gradients and the transitions of course . Thanks.