# Reach parent of :checked input

Tags: html, css

Can you please help me? How can I in css reach .switch if input is checked?
I googled and tried this: (I basically want to change background if is input:checked)

```
.switch:has(>input:checked) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

but it didnt worked.

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox"">
<div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

I know that there could be some way to do it in js, but is there way in css?

Thank you so much guys.

Comment: Not possible to refer to the parent ... but what you want to change ?? .. check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39375149/2887133

Comment: has() isn't really supported yet ---> http://caniuse.com/#search=has