# Scale transformation under flexbox renders differently in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox, css-transforms

I want to center a div, and then scale it (via transorm:scale) to be larger.

I use flexbox to center the div.
I want to use the entire view space so I give the HTML and BODY elements, a 100% height.

In Firefox it renders nicely.
In Chrome however, the scaling of the internal div seems to cause the BODY element to overflow, and a vertical scrollbar appears.

If you run the snippets below in Chrome and in Firefox you will notice the difference: the vertical scrollbar appears only in Chrome.  I want to make this look in Chrome just like it looks in Firefox (no scrollbar).

Can anyone help me figure this out ?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;   
  background-color: black;     
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  transform: scale(1.7);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44550095/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of margin consider `align-items`/`justify-content` to center the element. Chrome seems to also scale the margin causing this issue:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

div.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transform: scale(1.7);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```