# Targeting specific divs on post hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have two types of Wordpress posts which are wrapped in link tags and brought in through the loop.

html

```
<a id="article-image"> 
  <section> post content </section> 
  <div class="bg-Hide"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
<a id="article-title">
  <section> post content </section>
</div>
```

css

```
.bg-Hide { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0; 
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  top: 0; left: 0;  
  background-color: rgba(32, 42, 52, 0.75);
}
```

I want to change the opacity of .bg-Hide to  `opacity: 1;` when the user hovers over the .article-image posts

But can't seem to create the right css target

Comment: #article-image:hover > .bg-Hide {opacity:1;}

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS. You can't add styles to a parent element on hover of the child, at least not with pure CSS. Here's a somewhat related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39374918/3597276

Comment: I want to target .bg-Hide when #article-image is hovered on. but thought that there needs to be an 'a' in there also

Comment: Your code worked Jake, can't give you credit though since it's in the comments

Comment: Please note that you cannot have more than one `<a id="article-image">` or `<a id="article-title">` in the page as `id` **must be unique**.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.bg-Hide:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

In your css.

Comment: Also in your second snip make sure you are closing your section tag with </section>

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote it instead of copying and missed that