# Dim entire screen except a fixed area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a tutorial which will lead the user exactly where to click. I'm trying to cover the entire screen with a `<div>` which will dim all elements except a **specific region** which is in a fixed `width`, `height`, `top` and `left`.

The problem is, I cannot find a way to "cancel" the parent's `background-color` (which is also transparent).

In the snipped below, `hole` is the div that is supposed to be without any `background-color`, including its parent's.

Can this be accomplished at all? Any ideas?

```css
#bg{
   background-color:gray;
   opacity:0.6;
   width:100%;
   height:100vh;
}
#hole{
   position:fixed;
   top:100px;
   left:100px;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
    <div id="hole"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a mockup image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: If you're creating a feature tour / tutorial, you might be interested in one of the js libraries for doing this. They have some nifty features and will save you the trouble of writing a bunch of one-off css effects. Check out http://introjs.com/ or http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/.

Comment: This is just a suggestion for a lib: http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You could do it with just one `div` and give it a `box-shadow`.

**EDIT:** 
as @Nick Shvelidze pointed out, you should consider adding `pointer-events: none`

Added `vmax` value for `box-shadow` as @Prinzhorn suggested

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  /* for IE */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  /* for real browsers */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Be sure to add `pointer-events: none` if you want the area below it to be clickable.

Comment: 1,000px doesn't seem enough to me - seems like there would be too many cases where this doesn't fill the screen, otherwise really clever solution.

Comment: @EdmundReed you can adjust that for your needs :)

Comment: @VilleKoo oh absolutely, just wasn't sure that it would be clear to everyone reading.

Comment: `box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0,0,0,.3);` will be guaranteed to cover the whole screen

Comment: @Prinzhorn i don't think vmax is supported by IE

Comment: @VilleKoo you can add it behind the 1000px line and keep that as a fall back

Comment: @VilleKoo Then you'd better use `99999px` (or at least `9999px`) because `1000px` is not so big value.

Comment: Good solution. An explanation of how *box-shadow* works would be useful. Here's a similar post with a description of each *box-shadow* value. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39374918/3597276

Answer (score 20):

You can create an SVG which is filled with a path that has the hole where you need it to. But I guess than you need to find a way to handle clicks, since all of them will be targeted to the overlaid svg. I thing `document.getElementFromPoint` can help you here. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3Adocument.elementFromPoint)

Comment: i think google feedback form using svg to dim rest area.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done similarly to @VilleKoo's answer, but with a border.

```css
div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    border-width: 40px 300px 50px 60px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same as in [VilleKoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144078/1548895) using CSS [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property. It has excellent browser support (and works also in IE8+). Outlines have the same syntax as borders, but unlike border they don't take up space, they are drawn above the content.

Also for IE9+ you can replace `99999px` with `calc(100 * (1vh + 1vw - 1vmin))`.

Disadvantage of this approach is that `outline` is not affected by `border-radius`.

Demo:

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  /* IE8 */
  outline: 99999px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  /* IE9+ */
  outline: calc(100 * (1vw + 1vh - 1vmin)) solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  /* for other browsers */
  outline: 100vmax solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple jQuery code using @VilleKoo css

```js
var Dimmer = (function(){
  var el = $(".dimmer");
  
  return {
    showAt: function(x, y) {
      el
        .css({
          left: x,
          top: y,
        })
        .removeClass("hidden");
    },
    
    hide: function() {
      el.addClass("hidden");
    }
  }
}());


$(".btn-hide").click(function(){ Dimmer.hide(); });
$(".btn-show").click(function(){ Dimmer.showAt(50, 50); });
```

```css
.dimmer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.3); /* for IE */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0,0,0,.3); /* for real browsers */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <input type="text">
    <select name="" id=""></select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
    <select name="" id=""></select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
    <select name="" id=""></select>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" disabled>
  </div>
  
  <input type="button" value="Hide" class="btn-hide">
  <input type="button" value="Show" class="btn-show">
  <div class="dimmer hidden"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#bg {
   background-color: gray;
   opacity: 0.6;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 99998;
}
#hole {
   position: fixed;
   top: 100px;
   left: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   z-index: 99999;
}
```