# Can I update the style of the parents after element when an input inside it is focused using CSS/ SCSS?

Tags: css, input, sass, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Can I update the style of the parents after element when an input inside it is focused?

The design means I need to use an after element rather than styling the input with a border but i need to update the background colour of the after element when the input is focused. Can I do this just using SCSS / CSS?

HTML

```
<div class="subscribe__wrapper">
    <div class="subscribe__input">
        <input class="mr-medium" type="email" id="fields-emailAdress" required name="fields[email]"
            placeholder="Your email address">
    </div>
    <button class="next btn-rounded btn-rounded--small ml-min">
    </button>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.subscribe__wrapper {
position: relative;
&:after {
      content: '';
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 2px;
      background: $border-color;
      position: absolute; 
    }
}

.subscribe__wrapper input:focus {
  .subscribe__wrapper & {
     &:after {
          background: red;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems a little tricky -- I'm not sure that it's possible to do exactly what you need with the current element hierarchy. You could use `.subscribe__wrapper:focus-within:after {}`, however it would apply the focus styles when ANY focusable child is in focus, including the button.

If you move the `:after` styles into the `subscribe__input` class, you could use `focus-within` more reliably since theres only one focusable element in there

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39374918/3597276

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS and your current markup, no, it's not possible. [See this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element).

As suggested in the accepted answer to that question, though, you can modify your markup to add another element after the input and then style it using a sibling selector (`+` or `~`) when the input is in focus. This new element would have the background instead of putting it on a pseudo element of `.subscribe__wrapper`.

For example:

```css
.subscribe__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.subscribe__wrapper input:focus + .background {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="subscribe__wrapper">
  <div class="subscribe__input">
    <input class="mr-medium" type="email" id="fields-emailAdress" required name="fields[email]" placeholder="Your email address">
    <div class="background"></div>
  </div>
  <button class="next btn-rounded btn-rounded--small ml-min"></button>
</div>
```