# Style parent element differently depending on which child element is hovered | CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors, hover

I'm partially using a solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374918/on-hover-of-child-change-background-color-of-parent-container-css-only) question asked a while back.

I say *partially* because this solution only seems to work if you want to style the parent element **one** way based off of **one** child element. When you have two or more children ( elements ) like below and you want the first child to style the parent one color and the second child to style the parent element another; using `pointer-events` seems to fail.

In the gif below the **head** is hovered just fine as the child element selects the `table` parent behind it and colors a portion of the background to match it's color. All of the other elements however ( **body** and **foot** ) fail to look consistent when hovered. What's a CSS only solution to this?

[image]

Notice how the **body** and **foot** elements fail to change the `table` background to match their colors. The desired behavior is that of the **head** element at the top when it's hovered.

*Hover the children:*

```css
thead th:first-child, tbody td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
thead th:last-child, tbody td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}
tbody td:first-child, tfoot td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
tbody td:last-child, tfoot td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
thead th {
  background-color: #666;
}
tbody td {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
tfoot td {
  background-color: #eee;
}
thead th:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
tbody td:hover {
  background-color: #888;
}
tfoot td:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.22rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  table, th, td {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  table {
    width: 10rem;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 
      transparent 20%, #666 20% 46.5%, #eee 46.5% 70%, transparent 70% 100%
    );  
    pointer-events: none;
  }  
  table:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient( 
      transparent 20%, #333 20% 46.5%, #eee 46.5% 70%, transparent 70% 100%
    );  
  }  
</style>
<table>
  <thead> <tr> <th>head</th> </tr> </thead>
  <tbody> <tr> <td>body</td> </tr> </tbody>
  <tfoot> <tr> <td>foot</td> </tr> </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Edit:** I kept the code short so it's easier to see what's going on. If I'm going about this the wrong way and their is an easier way ( like rearranging my HTML and changing all of my CSS ) to get the desired result; I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the parent table `overflow: hidden`, removing all of the `pointer-event` styles and utilizing `box-shadow` on the table cells themselves when hovered seemed to solve all issues.

```css
thead th:first-child, tbody td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
thead th:last-child, tbody td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}
tbody td:first-child, tfoot td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
tbody td:last-child, tfoot td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
thead th {
  background-color: #666;
  position: relative;
}
tbody td {
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
}
tfoot td {
  background-color: #eee;
}
thead th:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
tbody td:hover {
  background-color: #888;
}
tfoot td:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial; font-size: 1.22rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  table, th, td {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  table {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10rem;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 
      transparent 20%, #666 20% 46.5%, #eee 46.5% 70%, transparent 70% 100%
    );  
  }  
  table:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient( 
      transparent 20%, #666 20% 46.5%, #eee 46.5% 70%, transparent 70% 100%
    );  
  }  
  thead th:hover { box-shadow: #333 0 0.75rem 0 0.25rem; }  
  tbody td:hover { box-shadow: #666 0 -0.75rem 0 0.25rem; }
  tfoot td:hover { box-shadow: #ccc 0 -0.75rem 0 0.25rem; }  
</style>
<table>
  <thead> <tr> <th>head</th> </tr> </thead>
  <tbody> <tr> <td>body</td> </tr> </tbody>
  <tfoot> <tr> <td>foot</td> </tr> </tfoot>
</table>
```